# how to get pop3 email to put a copy of all sent emails on the server in the sent folder

Tags: email, pop3, sent-items

by default pop3 emails bring down the incoming messages from the server, although you can tell it to leave a copy on the server so that if your using multi machines / devices they can all get it.

but im trying to set it up so that i can see copys of all the emails that ive sent on the server, is there a way that i can do this ?

the webmail on my server is horde.

I know that this happens default on imap, but we all share one main email at work (as well as individuals) and the problem with imap is that if someone opens the email it shows as open in every one else inboxs, so they dont read it and it slips down bellow other emails..

please advise if this is the correct place for this..

Comment: You really didn't need two separate questions for this - you could have just included this as an option in the other question http://superuser.com/questions/461281/make-imap-email-that-are-read-on-one-machine-show-as-unread-on-another-machine

Comment: Don't quote me but I don't think POP email has a Sent folder at all. The sent folder is client side